# Streaming radio in Android

Tags: music-player, streaming, internet-radio

I like a couple of Internet radios that I'm currently able to listen to using CorePlayer under Windows Mobile, VLC and WMP on PC. I own the .m3u files for both `www.radio21.ro` and `www.vibefm.ro`, but when trying to open with different players they won't get played. NSWPlayer crashes, RockPlayer says the file can't be played with System Player.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TuneIn Radio](https://market.android.com/details?id=tunein.player&hl=en), it has both stations, and it's great (and free)!

Answer (score 1):

[M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) files store playlists. The M3U files you are trying to run just have a list of URLs to the radio stations. You can only play M3U files on your Media Player if the player supports playing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc).

Click the "More" button with three dots in the lower right corner, click the "New stream" button and paste in your URL and you are done.

The main benefits are that VLC is free, open-source, has no ads and on top of that can play just about anything (video or audio).